# Magento 2: How to setup separate theme for desktop and mobile?

Tags: magento2, theme, configuration, mobile

I want to load device wise (like mobile and tablet) theme in Magento 2.

**How can I do that?**

I have tried below code in User Agent Rules but not working for me:

```
 iPhone|iPod|BlackBerry|Palm|Googlebot-Mobile|Mobile|mobile|mobi|Windows Mobile|Safari Mobile|Android|Opera Mini
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try to create multiple exceptions for each device [image]

Comment: Hi, can you help me? I tried this but on samsung tablet still loading desktop theme :(

/Mobile|iP(hone|od|ad)|Android|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Kindle|NetFront|Silk-Accelerated|(hpw|web)OS|Fennec|Minimo|Opera M(obi|ini)|Blazer|Dolfin|Dolphin|Skyfire|Zune/

Answer (score 1):

1. In Admin Panel go to **Content-> Design-> Configuration**
2. Choose the store that you need
3. In **Design Rule** section add new **User Agent Rules** with next string:

   ```
   /iPhone|iPod|BlackBerry|Palm|Googlebot-Mobile|Mobile|mobile|mobi|Windows Mobile|Safari Mobile|Android|Opera Mini/i
   ```

   and choose the needed theme for mobile

Answer (score 0):

Here is the tutorial for this:
https://youtu.be/v7R46oqkPBs

Answer (score 0):

I think the OP is looking at Magento 1.9 admin, while the responder is giving Magento 2.x admin instructions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below solution to catch every tablet and every mobile device for different theme.

I found one solution.

first you need to add user agent for tablet like as below.

```
/(tablet|ipad|playbook|silk)|(android(?!.*mobile))/i
```

with this user agent you will select every tablet device.

after that you need to add user agent for mobile device like as below.

```
/Mobile|iP(hone|od|ad)|Android|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Kindle|NetFront|Silk-Accelerated|(hpw|web)OS|Fennec|Minimo|Opera M(obi|ini)|Blazer|Dolfin|Dolphin|Skyfire|Zune/
```

with this user agent you will select mobile devices.

for more information about user agent you can check below link.

[image]

https://gist.github.com/dalethedeveloper/1503252

hope this answer will work for you.

Thank you