# I have added user agent rule for only mobile but reflected on iPad and Tablet in Magento 2 latest version

Tags: magento-enterprise

I have created two themes one is for mobile and other for desktop and tablet. 
I have added user agent rule for only mobile but reflected on iPad and Tablet in Magento 2 latest version.
can anyone know this issue..

Answer (score 0):

You can use below solution to catch every tablet and every mobile device for different theme.

I found one solution.

first you need to add user agent for tablet like as below.

```
/(tablet|ipad|playbook|silk)|(android(?!.*mobile))/i
```

with this user agent you will select every tablet device.

after that you need to add user agent for mobile device like as below.

```
/Mobile|iP(hone|od|ad)|Android|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Kindle|NetFront|Silk-Accelerated|(hpw|web)OS|Fennec|Minimo|Opera M(obi|ini)|Blazer|Dolfin|Dolphin|Skyfire|Zune/
```

with this user agent you will select mobile devices.

for more information about user agent you can check below link.

[image]

https://gist.github.com/dalethedeveloper/1503252

also you can refer this question.

[Magento 2: How to setup separate theme for desktop and mobile?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/155296/magento-2-how-to-setup-separate-theme-for-desktop-and-mobile/310755#310755)

hope this answer will work for you.

Thank you