# Magento 2: Desktop and Mobile Themes switched after flushing the cache

Tags: magento2, theme, cache, mobile-menu

I'm using two themes for Magento 2: Desktop Theme and Mobile Theme. But, I am facing a strange issue. After flushing the cache, If I refresh the site on my desktop, The Desktop version loads correctly. Then, If I open my Mobile and refresh the site, It also loads the desktop version! (Not Mobile version).

The same thing happens for the opposite process -  If I flush the cache, And refresh my site on my mobile first, It loads the Mobile version correctly. But When I go to desktop PC and refresh my site again, It loads the mobile version of my site !.

Comment: do  you get any solution? I have faced same issue.

Comment: Yes, I found the solution here - https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/155296/magento-2-how-to-setup-separate-theme-for-desktop-and-mobile